# Arm 7 How can I calculate x * 64 mod 2^64?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm7

I have a requirement that I have to multiply a 64 bit number which is stored in 2 seperate registers with 64 mod 2^64. In this case the two 32bit values are stored in R4(low) and R5(high) So far I have written this code:

```
LDR         R1,=Value
LDR         R2, [R1]
MOV         R3, #64
UMULL       R4, R5, R2, R3
MUL         R6, R4, R3
MUL         R7, R5, R3
MOV         R1, R6, LSR #32
MOV         R2, R7, LSR #32

Value       DCD         67108864
```

For the mod 2^64 part I do the last two MOV commands with 32 bit shifts. Is this correct? When I do this I always get the value 0 in R1 and R2. What can I do so that I dont get mod 2^64 = 0?

Comment: If it is a 64-bit integer number then isn't it always (and already) mod 2^64 if you ignore overflow?  That is, just shift it and you're done?

Comment: @DaveS Yea thats what I dont get sometimes. Some of the commands in our script have mod 2^32 or mod 2^64 behin the operation. For example ADDS R1, R2, R3 => R1 = R2 + R3 mod 2^32. So the mod 2^32 is there to check if you reached the "border" of 32 bit register?

Comment: Yes in some sense.  This `mod` is a mathematical way to remind you that there is no capture of result beyond the low order 32 bits; this is easy and natural for the hardware: there is no extra hardware or steps to do this mod operation.  Further, that describes that there is no overflow check automatically done; that the result is simply truncated for fitting back into a 32-bit register.  Should probably be `R1 = (R2 + R3) mod 2^32`.

Comment: @ErikEidt So my two MOV commands are obsolete? Only the 2 MUL commands are enough?

Comment: There's no need for any `mul` instructions, just shifting since you're multiplying by a power of 2.  (You do need to shift bits across the 32-bit boundary between low and high halves, though, possibly with shift/shift/OR, although ARM can fold one of those shifts into the OR.)

Comment: Yup, compiler output https://godbolt.org/z/4sz6fzanf uses lsl / orr (with a shifted source) for the high half, then lsl for the low half.  I of course wrote a function instead of loading/storing a global.  Or with just a 32-bit source, only two shifts.

Comment: Ok I see what youre saying, basically this after the UMULL: `MOV R6,R4, LSL #6` and `MOV R7, R5, LSL #6` Both high and low shifted by 6 Bits 2^6 = 64. And there are no other factors that I have to watch out for when doing this. What if I multiply the value 2^30 * 64? Wouldnt I get issues?

Comment: @Florent: Yes, just the shifts alone would give the wrong high half; that would shift zeros into the high half where it should have the high bits of the low half shifted in.  So that's why you need the `ORR` in between, which you can see if you look closely at the compiler output Peter linked.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes thanks, I forgot to write something back here. I got it now. Thanks for you all to help me understand this.